# How to set ellipsis for a TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ellipsis

I have the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nm85L6dr/

HTML:

```
<div class="module fade">
  <span>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</span>
</div>

<table>
    <tr class="module fade">
        <td>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way to set the elipsis for a TD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move rule to `<td>` and set `position: absolute`.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font: 1.2em/1.2em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.module {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.module span, .module td {
  margin: 0;
}

.fade {
  position: relative;
  height: 3.6em; /* exactly three lines */
}
.fade:after {
  content: "";
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 1.2em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%);
}

td.fade { 
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="module fade">
  <span>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</span>
</div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="module fade">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```